# How to read multiple results of SOAP response using Spring and Jaxb2?

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to get datas from an external webservice with SOAP on Spring, following this guide : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/#initial
When I expect only one response, it works very well, but when I get many responses as below (for exemple several users), I can't read each user.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns:xsd="...">
   <soap:Body>
      <UserResponse xmlns="...">
         <Users>
            <User>
               <NAME>...</NAME>
               <SURNAME>...</SURNAME>
            </User>   
            <User>
               <NAME>...</NAME>
               <SURNAME>...</SURNAME>
            </User>  
         <Users>
      </UserResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here are the generated class :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"userResult"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "UserResponse")
public class Users {

    @XmlElement(name = "Users")
    protected User user;

//GETTER/SETTER
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User", propOrder = {"name", "surname"})
public class User{

    @XmlElement(name = "NAME")
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "SURNAME")
    protected String surname;

//GETTER/SETTER
```

How can I read each User ? I tryed to change the generated class making a List of User in Users class but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: You only get 1 response... Which is `Users` which should contain a collection of `User` objects. At least that is what the response looks like. The WSDL of that web service (and XSD) should reflect that. Apparently they don't (or you didn't generate the classes but wrote them by hand).

Comment: I added a class ArrayOfUser and put it in Users Class, it works well :)
Thank you !

Comment: I have the same problem. Any news on that topic ?